# Replace control characters with sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

as I'm quite unfamiliar with sed (or any other tool that mayfit), I have the following question:
I have a string that contains control characters which must be replaced with the actual function. These control characters have no effect so far.

i.e.:

original string:

```
Rating..........Red\nAlert.Name......High Update Response Time\nManaged.Object..D0P~ABAP~sap00d0p_D0P_48
```

should become:

```
Rating..........Red
Alert.Name......High Update Response Time
Managed.Object..D0P~ABAP~sap00d0p_D0P_48
```

How can I achieve this with sed (or appropriate tools)

**Edited:** Script is as followed:

```
function specChars { s=$1 echo -e "$s" }
SERVICENAME=\"$(specChars "$1")\" >> /export/home/ovolog/solman/test.log
printf "\n"
echo (specChars "$1")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no control characters. Just `echo -e` to display this string:

```
s='Rating..........Red\nAlert.Name......High Update Response Time\nManaged.Object..D0P~ABAP~sap00d0p_D0P_48'

echo -e "$s"
Rating..........Red
Alert.Name......High Update Response Time
Managed.Object..D0P~ABAP~sap00d0p_D0P_48
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast!
This helps at first sight.
The problem is that i need to "manipulate" this string so that I can use it further in this script.
Echo would just do an output on the console

Comment: @user3322838: You can use/manipulate the string in rest of your script. Where exactly are you facing problem in this manipulation?

Comment: I have to use this manipulated String in a ssh command, so the String has the actual line feeds (and so on) in the target system.
When i test it with a logfile, the line feeds are not presented there.
See:
function specChars {
 s=$1
 echo -e "$s"
}
printf "\n"
(specChars "$1")


echo SERVICENAME=\"$(specChars "$1")\" >>/export/home/ovolog/solman/test.log

the (specChars "$1") gives the desired result in console, but the logfile entry is still 1 lined

Comment: well, the format of this answer field is pretty bad. I hope you understand what I mean though

Comment: Yes difficult to read, can you edit your question and paste this script there.

Comment: btw `echo -e "$s" > test.log` prints output properly formatted in the file.

Comment: Added script to the original question. The pipe to the logfile is just a test. At the end the formatted string should be sent to another target system via ssh

Comment: This string can be sent anywhere using ssh also. Whatever system interprets it will do so with the knowledge that there are newlines in the string. btw your `SERVICENAME=\"$(specChars "$1")\" >> /export/home/ovolog/solman/test.log` is wrong. It should be just: `SERVICENAME="$(specChars "$1")"`. Also your function must be: **`function specChars { echo -e "$1" }`**

Comment: the \" before $(specChars "$1") is needed because the target system needs these " ;)
It works, thanks for your really great help @anubhava!